# Which version of Python is used on Quickly?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, versions

I'd like to know the Python version used on Quickly. I could not find the version on the Wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check here: [Package: quickly](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/quickly) on http://packages.ubuntu.com/

You will see that it depends on the package python.

Which on 12.04 is version 2.7.3 
on 13.04 it's 2.7.4

For other releases of Ubuntu in a terminal enter

```
python --version
```

The number returned is the version of python its using.

If you want to use python3 instead take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/293184/107450)